# Java GUI jTable: Insert link to remove its row from table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like add a link in my jTable. This jTable has some cells filled with a person's firstname, and lastname. In the 3rd cell I need this link to remove the person from this table. Is this possible?

For now I have something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    Person person = persons.get(i);
    jTabelRoster.setValueAt(lid.getPersonFirstname(), i, 0);
    jTabelRoster.setValueAt(lid.getPersonLastname(), i, 1);
}
```

on the 3rd horizontal position I want this link :)

Is this possible?

Comment: you mean it is an action like when we click it, the row will be deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Table Button Column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) for a solution that uses a button in a column to do the delete.

Answer (score 2):

You can have `CheckBox` column by which you can select the rows that you want for `deletion`. Below example show one approach. You can select a row and then click on delete to delete the row.

Example code which I have with me.

[image: Row Deletion]

**TableExample.java** (UI-class)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class TableExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableExample().createUI();
            }
        };

        EventQueue.invokeLater(r);
    }

    private void createUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
        JButton delBtn = new JButton("Delete");
        JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        buttonPnl.add(addBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(delBtn);

        final StudentTableModel tableModel = new StudentTableModel();
        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(tableModel);
        table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);

        addBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                StudentDO do1 = new StudentDO();
                do1.setName("Student " + tableModel.getRowCount());
                do1.setAge(tableModel.getRowCount());
                tableModel.addRow(do1);
            }
        });

        delBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tableModel.deleteRow();
            }
        });

        frame.add(table.getTableHeader(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setTitle("JTable Example.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**StudentTableModel.java** (TableModel class)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<StudentDO> data;
    private List<String> columnNames;

    public StudentTableModel() {
        data = getTableDataList();
        columnNames = getColumnNamesList();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return Boolean.class;
        case 1: 
            return String.class;
        case 2: 
            return Integer.class;
        default:
            return String.class;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex == 0 ? true : false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames.get(column);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            return data.get(rowIndex).isSelect();
        case 1:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getName();
        case 2:
            return data.get(rowIndex).getAge();
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
        case 0:
            data.get(rowIndex).setSelect((Boolean) aValue);
            break;
        case 1:
            data.get(rowIndex).setName(aValue != null ? aValue.toString() : null);
            break;
        case 2:
            data.get(rowIndex).setAge(aValue != null ? Integer.parseInt(aValue.toString()) : null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    public void addRow(StudentDO do1) {
        data.add(do1);
        fireTableRowsInserted(getRowCount() - 1, getRowCount() - 1);
    }

    public void deleteRow() {
        for(int rowIndex = data.size() - 1; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--) {
            if(data.get(rowIndex).isSelect()) {
                data.remove(rowIndex);
            }
        }

        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    private List<StudentDO> getTableDataList() {

        List<StudentDO> list = new ArrayList<StudentDO>();

        StudentDO do1 = null;
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            do1 = new StudentDO();
            do1.setSelect(false);
            do1.setName("Student " + i);
            do1.setAge(i);

            list.add(do1);
        }

        return list;
    }

    private List<String> getColumnNamesList() {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

        names.add("Select");
        names.add("Name");
        names.add("Age");

        return names;
    }
}
```

**StudentDO.java** (Student class)

```
public class StudentDO {

    private boolean select;
    private String name;
    private int age;

        // Add getter's and setter's
}
```

Comment: an alternative, could be easiest of ways